# How to ffmpeg command execution in ffmpeg4android app

Tags: android, ffmpeg

If i m using ffmpeg4android Play store app and executing command for video trim but they are not working i m using below command for trimming

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vide.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -t 00:12:00 -async 1 /sdcard/cut.mp4
```

Above Command Execute but not showing file cut.mp4 in sdcard .if you know another way for video trimming then show me example or link Thanks in Advance

If i m running this command showing Logcat

Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
 /sdcard/vide.mp4: No such file or directory
I m already add file in sdcard path

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your command is perfectly right. I tried it myself in Ffmpeg4android.  Now there can be multiple isssue for command not giving result.

Check whether the path of video you are giving is complete or not. Also add `-y` to overwrite o/p. As this app will not run command to overwrite o/p on its own.

Next  add `-strict experimental` to your command. I know its not necessary for your command but it solves nightmares in Ffmeg4android.

And lastly check **Show last run log** option in client app. It gives complete detailing of where your command is going wrong.

Last option will surely help you. Cheers.:)

Comment: @Sanket990 accept/vote answr if it worked for you! Else write your followup problem.

Comment: but how to know progressbar process is compete or not (Command execution complete or not)